# Select from 2 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

There are the tables:

User

```
id | login | password | creationDate
_____________________________________
 1 | user1 | 123 | 12.12.12 
 2 | user2 | 123 | 12.12.12
 3 | user3 | 123 | 12.12.12
```

AdditionalParams

```
id | userId | name    | value
_______________________________
 1 | 1      | petName | jim
 2 | 1      | houseNum| 2
 3 | 1      | favTea  | black
 4 | 2      | favTea  | black
 5 | 2      | petName | jam
 6 | 3      | favTea  | green
 7 | 3      | lang    | C++
 8 | 3      | petName | jem
```

So, it contains diff. data for diff. users, and not all of them have the same array of additional prams;

My goal is to select something like that *"select all users with theirs petNames, but only if favTea=black":*

Result

```
User.id | User.login | User.password | petName
_____________________________________________
 1      | user1      | 123           | jim
 2      | user2      | 123           | jam
```

I've tried many variants, but non of them return what i want. 
Here is the lasm my try:

```
WITH Results_CTE AS
(
SELECT  DISTINCT AdditionalParams.value,
User.id as 'id',
User.login as 'login',
User.password as 'password',
User.creationDate as 'creationDate',
AdditionalParams.value as 'pet'
FROM User
INNER JOIN AdditionalParams
ON User.id = AdditionalParams.userId
WHERE AdditionalParams.name = 'PetName' AND 
AdditionalParams.value = 'black' AND 
AdditionalParams.name = 'PetName' OR AdditionalParams.name = 'favTea' 
)
SELECT
id as 'id',
login as 'login',
password as 'password',
status as 'status',
batchType as 'batchType',
creationDate as 'creationDate',
ExportDate as 'ExportDate',
pet as 'pet'
FROM Results_CTE
```

PS: DataBase is MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: You have some missing parenthesis in your cte. You have (name = 'petname' and value = 'black' and name = 'petname') OR name = 'favtea' Why do you even have tea in this? It looks like you want petName only? You are also aliasing all your columns with string literals, which is a bit strange, but the alias is the same as the column name, Those aliases are pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT u.id, u.login, u.password, ap2.value AS petName
FROM User AS u
INNER JOIN AdditionalParams AS ap 
  ON u.Id = ap.userId AND ap.name = 'favTea' AND ap.value = 'black'
LEFT JOIN AdditionalParams AS ap2 ON u.Id = ap2.userId AND ap2.name = 'petName'
```

It's just a query with two `JOIN` operations. The predicates of the `ON` clause implement the 'business' logic.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8a172/1)

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark but I think you could replace your entire query with something this simple. Please note that storing passwords in clear text is horrific. Passwords should be salted and hashed at all times. The original value should NOT be recoverable. I would also make the join the AdditionalParams a left join in case somebody doesn't have a pet.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    User.id
    , User.login
    , User.password 
    , User.creationDate
    , AdditionalParams.value as 'pet'
FROM User u
LEFT JOIN AdditionalParams ap ON u.id = ap.userId
WHERE ap.name = 'PetName'
```

Answer (score 0):

1) it is probably better to replace `inner` with `left`

```
select u.*, p.value as petname
from users u
inner join AdditionalParams p on p.userid = u.id and p.Name= 'petName'
where exists(
  select 1 from AdditionalParams pp
  where pp.userid = u.id and pp.Name= 'favTea' and pp.value = 'black')
```

2) same approach with `inner join` instead of `exists`

3) pivot

```
;with Users as
(
  select 1 as id, 'user1' as userlogin
  union all
  select 2, 'user2'
  union all
  select 3, 'user3'
),
AdditionalParams as
(
  select 1 as id, 1 as userid, cast('petName' as varchar(100)) as name, cast('jim' as varchar(100)) as value
  union all
  select 2, 1, 'houseNum', '2'
  union all
  select 3, 1, 'favTea', 'black'
  union all
  select 4, 2, 'favTea', 'black'
  union all
  select 5, 2, 'houseNum', '2'
  union all
  select 6, 3, 'favTea', 'green'
  union all
  select 7, 3, 'lang', 'C++'
  union all
  select 8, 3, 'petName', 'jem'
),
PivotedParams as
(
  select p.*
  from 
  (
    select p.userid, u.userlogin, p.name as paramname, p.value
    from Users u
    inner join AdditionalParams p on p.userid = u.id
  ) up
  PIVOT (MAX(up.Value) FOR paramname in ([petName], [favtea]))  p
)
select * 
from PivotedParams p
where p.favtea = 'black'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Pivot. If your name column in Additional parameter table is dynamic then you can try using with dynamic pivot.

```
SELECT  U.id, U.login, U.password, T.Petname
FROM
(
    SELECT  userid, name, value
    from    AdditionalParams
) AS T JOIN User AS U ON U.id = T.userid
PIVOT
(
    MAX(value)
    for name
    IN([petName], [favTea], [lang], houseNum)
) as pivoting
where favTea = 'Black'
```